# How to parse C++ protobuf binary data by python protobuf?

Tags: python, c++, protocol-buffers

I use C++ protobuf to serialize data to string.

```
/***** cpp code *****/
string serialized_data;
message_cpp.SerializeToString(&serialized_data);
```

**Question:** can I parse `serialized_data` in python? and how?

I've tried the following code, but it did not work.

```
##### python code
message_python = foo.ParseFromString(serialized_data)
print message_python
```

But I get `None` as the output of `print message_python`. I've also tried

```
##### python code
message_python = foo.MergeFromString(serialized_data)
print message_python
```

But I get the length of string `serialized_data` as the output of `print message_python`, i.e. `message_python == len(serialized_data)`. This result agrees with [python protobuf API](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python/google.protobuf.message.Message-class#MergeFromString).

Does this means that I cannot parse the binary data in python, which are serialized in C++?

**Update:**

My *goal*： C++ server always generates image stream and image is sent to a python server.

Here are my whole codes:

.proto file:

```
message MyImage{
    repeated int32 width = 1;
    repeated int32 height = 2;
    repeated bytes image = 3;
}
```

C++ server:

```
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REP);
socket.bind("tcp://localhost:5555");

MyImage message_cpp;
// message_cpp.add_image(), add_width() and add_height() here.

string serialized_data;
message_cpp.SerializeToString(&serialized_data);
int counter = 3;
while (counter > 0) {
    zmq::message_t request;
    socket.recv(&request);
    std::string replyMessage = std::string(static_cast<char *>(request.data()),
                                           request.size());
    std::cout << "Recived from client: " + replyMessage << std::endl;
    sleep(1);
    zmq::message_t reply(serialized_data.size());
    memcpy((void*) reply.data(), serialized_data.data(), serialized_data.size());
    std::cout << "---length of message to client: " << 
                  reply.size() << std::endl;
    socket.send(reply);

    counter --;
}
```

python client:

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
port = "5555"
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s" %port)
print "Connecting to server..."
foo = my_image_pb2.MyImage()

for i in range(3):
    socket.send("hello from python")
    serialized_data = socket.recv()
    message_python = foo.ParseFromString(serialized_data)
    print "length of message from server:", len(serialized_data),"; type:", type(message)
    print "-----", message_python
```

This is the result:

server:

[image: server]

client:

[image: client]

Why the `foo` is `None`, not a class? Any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: Uhm, it shouldn't matter in which language the protobuf binary data was created. To make that transparent is protobuf's mere purpose. Also `message_cpp.SerializeToString(&serialized_data);` doesn't produce protobuf binary data, but a string as the name says.

Comment: You do not say by what means you transfer the serialized_data from C++ to Python. (E.g. saving them to file in C++ and loading in Python.) Did you verify that you get the same data across?

Comment: The message data is contained in 'foo', you can print foo to get the actual human readable message data after ParseFromString.

Comment: I update my question to make it clear :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I update my question. I serialize data into string because value type of data fed to zmq_send() is `string`. But the result of client seems `serialized_data` is not a regular string.

Comment: @michalsrb I want to realize the inter-process communication, so I do not save the data in C++ and load them in python.

Comment: @DongLi You woke me now at the left foot getting up from my coffin. BAD CALL. Introducing zmq opens a completely new realm.

Comment: @rfkortekaas I update my question and print some results.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry... I'm in China, so it's morning now... Sorry again.

Comment: @DongLi It wasn't that much abiout the daylight zone, but introducing ZMQ. That opens a quite broad field.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I used ZMQ before and it‘s really a sharp sword in IPC field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ParseFromString` parses *into* the object it is called on. It doesn't return anything. Use it like:

```
message = MyMessage()
message.ParseFromString(data)
print message
```

Comment: I updated my question just now. If I want to recover my image info from `data` in your answer, what should I do?

Comment: @DongLi After you call `foo.ParseFromString()`, your data is now inside `foo`. You can access `foo.width`, `foo.height`, `foo.image`. `foo.ParseFromString()` does NOT return anything; it fills in `foo` with the message content.